# Returning query fragments

Tags: javascript, regex, browser, dom-events

I have an url that looks like this:

```
https://example.com/?category=123&dk=sports&dk=groupcompanyinsider&dk=local&lang=en
```

1. Is it possible to return every dk parameter separately? (no matter if there will be 1 or 5 dk parameters) so i would get separately sports, groupcompanyinsider, local.
2. If its not possible maybe there is a way to return all of them in one string like `dk=sports&dk=groupcompanyinsiderlocal&dk=local` ?

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in javascript class URLSearchParams for this.
You can then transform this into the string you want with string concatenation and a foreach.

```js
const url = "https://example.com/?category=123&dk=sports&dk=groupcompanyinsider&dk=local&lang=en";

var params = new URLSearchParams(url);
var result = "";

// concatenate individual values of the 'dk' query parameter
params.getAll('dk').forEach(function (item) {
    result += '&dk=' + item;
});

result = result.substr(1); // remove starting '&' from the result;
console.log(result);
```

The result should contain your desired string.